# Advantages and disadvantages of deploying a client's application to my own Heroku/S3 account

Tags: untagged

**Note: This is not a technical question. I hope it's appropiate to ask here**

Well, I developed an application for a client to manage his business. Only workers will be able to login, however they want to be able to login from any physical location so we are deploying it to the cloud. The stack is Heroku+S3.

So far I deployed clients' apps to my own Heroku and S3 account, and they pay the bills in advance(the traffic is really predictable), but lately I'm starting to think that maybe there's some advantages in creating Heroku+S3 accounts for each client and then deploy/manage there.

Also, I'm pretty sure there's also disadvantages to this approach, like for example the fact that I would have to manage different credentials for each app in my development machine.

Any ideas, insights or experiences worth sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to make some additional money with the hosting or do you just invoice the amount you get billed by the cloud provider?

If not creating separate accounts will make things easier for you as there's a direct contract between the provider and your customer. So they pay their bills directly and if something breaks they have to blame the hoster.

Of course you'll have to manage different accounts but this also got the advantage that when someone manages to get your login credentials he might just have access to one instance (and not those of all your customers).

Comment: With regard to the additional money, it's a good idea but I guess it's 1) not my intention and 2) not really feasible, since at some point the client will ask for the bills, in order to declare his expenses(taxes etc). And great point about multiple accounts being more secure since they are independent from each other.